# When is WIN64 pre-compilation constant evaluated in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

When does WIN64 compilation constant get evaluated in VBA? Will it evaluate only on the developer's machine or it will evaluate on the user's machine as well?

For example what does the following code do when it is developed on 32bit Office Application but is being run on a 64bit Office Application?

```
#IF WIN64 THEN
   MsgBox "A"
#ELSE
   MsgBox "B"
#END IF
```

Comment: #IF is a compiler directive and is used to select which code to compile based on the value of a #DEFINEd constant.  So yes, it will be on every machine.

Comment: @BigBen I already red the documentation. the problem is documentation doesn't specify when the code is compiled. I know that VBA code is Compiled to p-code then if that p-code is used, it becomes only once on developer machine.

Comment: @pixo Consider what would happen if it was set in stone on your computer. It would then fail for users who have configurations different from your computer. Which would defeat the entire purpose, so quite logically it does not happen that way.

Comment: BigBen thanks for the link. but still my main question remains, I updated the code so that it is not covered by that link. @GSerg but if its being compiled to pcode then compilation constant is already evaluated in developer's machine. but I agree this should not happen logically.

Comment: I don't have a MSFT source, but [this](https://www.mandiant.com/resources/purgalicious-vba-macro-obfuscation-with-vba-purging) claims: When a VBA macro is added to a document, the VBA engine saves a compiled version in the PerformanceCache (i.e. P-code) section of the relevant module stream to increase performance. However, an Office application will only access the PerformanceCache if its version and architecture match what was used to compile the original VBA code. ... If the versions do not match, the compressed source code is decompressed, compiled, and run instead. Perhaps helpful.

Comment: @BigBen yes that was helpful, I would consider mandiant reliable. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is compiled to the executable file. Instead, it is parsed and executed on each machine separately. So, on both machines x86 and x64 ones the constant is re-evaluated and the code is run depending on the environment. See [64-bit Visual Basic for Applications overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview) for more information on that.